# How to make cell bigger for few seconds?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollection with some cells, I want that cell after cell each one will be "chosen" - change size to be bigger and change the background color and stay like this for a few seconds before it get back to normal. I could not find something like that in the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code on the CollectionView's delegate:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let scale: CGFloat = 1.2
    let animationDuration = 0.5
    let delay = 4.0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration, animations: {
        collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
    }) { (c) in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration, delay: delay, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
            collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)?.transform = .identity
        })
    }
}
```